# Conditional rendering via JSON in React

Tags: reactjs, json, conditional-statements, rendering

Hope someone can help me. Right now, I am switching from PHP + MySQL to React + NextJS and therefore I am a complete newbie – so please forgive me if the answer to my question is dead simple XD.

I want to render a link if I have an image or video for it in my database that the link should then point to. I have saved all the relevant data in JSON format in a variable, which is then used to display everything in a table.

**My code currently looks like this**

*The JSON*

```
const allDeliveries = [
  {
    category: "Category 1",
    items: [
      {
        amount: "2",
        name: "name 1",
        source: {
          name: "irrelevant link name 1",
          link: "irrelevant link 1",
        },
        hasMedia: true,
        media: [
          "media link 1",
          "media link 2",
        ],
        details: {
          name: "irrelevant link name 2",
          link: "irrelevant link 2",
        },
      },
      {
        amount: "2",
        name: "name 2",
        source: {
          name: "irrelevant link name 1",
          link: "irrelevant link 1",
        },
        hasMedia: false,
        media: null,
        details: {
          name: "irrelevant link name 2",
          link: "irrelevant link 2",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

*The relevant table part*

```
<tbody className="tailwind styles">
    {allDeliveries.map((allDeliveries) => (
      <Fragment key={allDeliveries.category}>
        <tr className="tailwind styles">
          <th
            colSpan={5}
            scope="colgroup"
            className="tailwind styles"
          >
            {allDeliveries.category}
          </th>
        </tr>
        {allDeliveries.items.map((items, itemsIdx) => (
          <tr
            key={items.name}
            className={classNames(
              itemsIdx === 0
                ? "tailwind styles"
                : "tailwind styles",
              "tailwind styles"
            )}
          >
            <td className="tailwind styles">
              {items.amount}
            </td>
            <td className="tailwind styles">
              {items.name}
            </td>
            <td className="tailwind styles">
              <a
                href={items.source.link}
                target="_blank"
                className="tailwind styles"
              >
                {items.source.name}
              </a>
            </td>
            <td className="tailwind styles">
              {items.media}
            </td>
            <td className="tailwind styles">
              <a
                href={items.details.link}
                target="_blank"
                className="tailwind styles"
              >
                {items.details.name}
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </Fragment>
    ))}
</tbody>
```

Now comes the tricky part. I only want to render a link where currently {items.media} gets rendered when the *hasMedia* in the JSON is set to true and then insert the *items.media* link. I must have watched tutorials on the subject of conditional rendering for an hour or two now, but I'm just not getting anywhere. Hopefully someone can help me. Thank you!

I've watched YouTube videos and other tutorials for the last one or two hours, tried to use the shown code and implement it on my project, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer** (as per comment):

Instead of `{items.media}`, you would check if `media` value is non falsy (not null or not undefined) and if it isn't: loop over the strings/links.

```
{items.media && items.media.map((link, i) => <a key={link} href={link}>Media {i + 1}</a>)}
```

[More Info: Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

```js
console.log(true && "something"); // will evaluate to "something"
console.log(false && "something"); // will evaluate to false

// So in the solution I have shown: if first expression is true (media "has items"*), it will then evaluate your array.map function for you

// * checking for null or undefined value
```

---

---

**Old answer:**

```
{allDeliveries.items.map((items, itemsIdx) => {
  if (!items.hasMedia) {
     return null;
  }
  return (
   <tr key={items.name}>
     ...
   </tr>
  )}
}
```

Pay attention to brackets.

---

```
{array.map((item) => <div key={item.key}>...</div>)}
/* OR */
{array.map((item) => (<div key={item.key}>...</div>))}
```

are shorthands of:

```
{array.map((item) => {
  /* you can set variables here or do conditional checks */
  return <div key={item.key}>...</div>;
})}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I did that, I wouldn't get anything displayed. I only want a single cell in the table to remain empty, not that no results are displayed at all.

Comment: I have added an image of the table (without the data) so you maybe know better what I want to archive.
[link](https://i.imgur.com/Y1eIQAa.png)

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me a lot and yeah, like I said, the answer to my question was pretty simple. Thanks again!